# Derivation of the mathematical equivalent of NOT operation

Tags: computer-science

I was browsing wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) when I came across this mathematical equivalent of the bitwise NOT operation.

I can't find a derivation of this anywhere and wondered if anyone knows where it comes from?

[image: Mathematical equivalent of the Bitwise NOT operation]

Comment: "The bitwise complement is equal to the two's complement of the value minus one. If two's complement arithmetic is used, then NOT x = -x − 1."

Comment: The [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of an N-bit number is defined as its complement with respect to $2^N$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.